# How can I cast an object using a known Type object?

Tags: c#, casting

I have a Type variable and I need to cast another object to it. (one which I know what the type is, but currently its an "object" type).  I need to do this for reasons that aren't really important to the answer.

```
// Pseudocode
MyObjectClass myTypedVar = new MyObjectClass();

Type myKnownType = myTypedVar.GetType();

var anotherObject = (myKnownType) anObjectVarThatIsReallyMyObjectClass;
```

I've read this page [Type Casting an Object using a "Type" Object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374440/type-casting-an-object-using-a-type-object-in-c-sharp) and I understand but I don't think it applies directly.  I anticipate a solution using reflection, but I just haven't been able to figure it out myself.

Comment: Use Convert.ChangeType.

Comment: Good lord.  Facepalm.

Comment: " need to do this for reasons that aren't really important to the answer" Sure that´s important. In particular it is important to know what you want to do with the object once casted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use the `Convert.ChangeType` method:

```
var anotherObject = Convert.ChangeType(anObjectVarThatIsReallyMyObjectClass, myKnownType);
```

You won't get any kind of compile-time checking when using a dynamic type like this though. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this.

**Generic type parameters and dynamic types in C#:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/10/31/generic-type-parameters-and-dynamic-types-in-csharp/